# is it possible to use amazon cognito with Kinesis data stream, to act as producer(producer is angular app )?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to write data from my angular app to amazon kinesis. Since aws cognito provide access to use the aws resources such as s3, is it possible to use with kinesis. I searched a lot. But could find any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly you can. Cognito identity pool will give you authAccess role which you can edit to give permission for AWS Kinesis.
You will first have to create a User Pool, then create an identity pool(federated identity) and add user pool in the authentication providers list. Then simply edit the authrole created for this identity pool and add kinesis rights.

Comment: it makes sense. But I couldn't find any documentation. And, in identity pool, Am I supposed to make everyone's rights manually ?.

Comment: For access control you can see this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html